# .net core 3.1 docker build CS0101 and CS0579 erros

Tags: .net, docker, asp.net-core-mvc, docker-build

I have asp.net core 3.1 project that references some other libraries from the same solution. When I want to build image everything ok until `RUN dotnet publish "MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish` command. When try to publish first of all I get CS2008: No source files specified and then I get so many CS0101 and CS0579 errors.

Docker build Command:

```
PS D:\VsProjects\MicroRabbit> docker build -t microrabitbanking -f MicroServicesRabitMq/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api/Dockerfile .
```

Docker File:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MicroServicesRabitMq/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api.csproj", "MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api/"]
COPY ["MicroServicesRabitMq/MicroServicesRabitMq.Infra.IoC/MicroServicesRabitMq.Infra.IoC.csproj", "MicroServicesRabitMq.Infra.IoC/"]
COPY ["MicroServicesRabitMq/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Application/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Application.csproj", "MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Application/"]
COPY ["MicroServicesRabitMq/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Data/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Data.csproj", "MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Data/"]
COPY ["MicroServicesRabitMq/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Domain/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Domain.csproj", "MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Domain/"]
COPY ["MicroServicesRabitMq/MicroServicesRabitMq.Domain.Core/MicroServicesRabitMq.Domain.Core.csproj", "MicroServicesRabitMq.Domain.Core/"]
COPY ["MicroServicesRabitMq/MicroServicesRabitMq.Transfer.Data/MicroServicesRabitMq.Transfer.Data.csproj", "MicroServicesRabitMq.Transfer.Data/"]
COPY ["MicroServicesRabitMq/MicroServicesRabitMq.Transfer.Domain/MicroServicesRabitMq.Transfer.Domain.csproj", "MicroServicesRabitMq.Transfer.Domain/"]
COPY ["MicroServicesRabitMq/MicroServicesRabitMq.Infra.Bus/MicroServicesRabitMq.Infra.Bus.csproj", "MicroServicesRabitMq.Infra.Bus/"]
COPY ["MicroServicesRabitMq/MicroServicesRabitMq.Transfer.Application/MicroServicesRabitMq.Transfer.Application.csproj", "MicroServicesRabitMq.Transfer.Application/"]
RUN dotnet restore "MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api"
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "MicroServicesRabitMq/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api.dll"]
```

erors:

```
CSC : warning CS2008: No source files specified. [/src/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Domain/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Domain.csproj]
  MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Domain -> /src/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Domain/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Domain.dll
  MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Data -> /src/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Data/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Data.dll
  MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Application -> /src/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Application/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Application.dll
  MicroServicesRabitMq.Infra.Bus -> /src/MicroServicesRabitMq.Infra.Bus/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/MicroServicesRabitMq.Infra.Bus.dll
  MicroServicesRabitMq.Transfer.Domain -> /src/MicroServicesRabitMq.Transfer.Domain/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/MicroServicesRabitMq.Transfer.Domain.dll
  MicroServicesRabitMq.Transfer.Application -> /src/MicroServicesRabitMq.Transfer.Application/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/MicroServicesRabitMq.Transfer.Application.dll
  MicroServicesRabitMq.Transfer.Data -> /src/MicroServicesRabitMq.Transfer.Data/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/MicroServicesRabitMq.Transfer.Data.dll
  MicroServicesRabitMq.Infra.IoC -> /src/MicroServicesRabitMq.Infra.IoC/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/MicroServicesRabitMq.Infra.IoC.dll
MicroServicesRabitMq/MicroServicesRabitMq.WebApp/obj/Release/netcoreapp3.1/Razor/Views/Home/Index.cshtml.g.cs(31,18): error CS0101: The namespace 'AspNetCore' already contains a definition for 'Views_Home_Index' [/src/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api.csproj]
MicroServicesRabitMq/MicroServicesRabitMq.WebApp/obj/Release/netcoreapp3.1/Razor/Views/Home/Privacy.cshtml.g.cs(31,18): error CS0101: The namespace 'AspNetCore' already contains a definition for 'Views_Home_Privacy' [/src/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api.csproj]
MicroServicesRabitMq/MicroServicesRabitMq.WebApp/obj/Release/netcoreapp3.1/Razor/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml.g.cs(31,18): error CS0101: The namespace 'AspNetCore' already contains a definition for 'Views_Shared_Error' [/src/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api.csproj]
MicroServicesRabitMq/MicroServicesRabitMq.WebApp/obj/Release/netcoreapp3.1/Razor/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml.g.cs(31,18): error CS0101: The namespace 'AspNetCore' already contains a definition for 'Views_Shared__Layout' [/src/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api.csproj]
MicroServicesRabitMq/MicroServicesRabitMq.WebApp/obj/Release/netcoreapp3.1/Razor/Views/Shared/_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml.g.cs(31,18): error CS0101: The namespace 'AspNetCore' already contains a definition for 'Views_Shared__ValidationScriptsPartial' [/src/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api.csproj]
MicroServicesRabitMq/MicroServicesRabitMq.WebApp/obj/Release/netcoreapp3.1/Razor/Views/_ViewImports.cshtml.g.cs(30,18): error CS0101: The namespace 'AspNetCore' already contains a definition for 'Views__ViewImports' [/src/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api.csproj]
MicroServicesRabitMq/MicroServicesRabitMq.WebApp/obj/Release/netcoreapp3.1/Razor/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml.g.cs(31,18): error CS0101: The namespace 'AspNetCore' already contains a definition for 'Views__ViewStart' [/src/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api.csproj]
MicroServicesRabitMq/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api/obj/Release/netcoreapp3.1/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api.AssemblyInfo.cs(13,12): error CS0579: Duplicate 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets.UserSecretsIdAttribute' attribute [/src/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api.csproj]
MicroServicesRabitMq/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api/obj/Release/netcoreapp3.1/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api.AssemblyInfo.cs(14,12): error CS0579: Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyFileVersionAttribute' attribute [/src/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api.csproj]
MicroServicesRabitMq/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api/obj/Release/netcoreapp3.1/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api.AssemblyInfo.cs(15,12): error CS0579: Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute' attribute [/src/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api.csproj]
MicroServicesRabitMq/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api/obj/Release/netcoreapp3.1/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api.AssemblyInfo.cs(16,12): error CS0579: Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyTitleAttribute' attribute [/src/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api.csproj]
MicroServicesRabitMq/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api/obj/Release/netcoreapp3.1/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api.AssemblyInfo.cs(17,12): error CS0579: Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyVersionAttribute' attribute [/src/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api.csproj]
MicroServicesRabitMq/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Application/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Application.AssemblyInfo.cs(14,12): error CS0579: Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyCompanyAttribute' attribute [/src/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api.csproj]
MicroServicesRabitMq/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Application/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Application.AssemblyInfo.cs(15,12): error CS0579: Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyConfigurationAttribute' attribute [/src/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api.csproj]
MicroServicesRabitMq/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Application/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Application.AssemblyInfo.cs(16,12): error CS0579: Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyFileVersionAttribute' attribute [/src/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api.csproj]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my dockerfile and now it is working. No need to add dependencies to docker file because When run dotnet publish dotnet knows to take dependent projects.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MicroServicesRabitMq/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api.csproj", "MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api/"]
RUN dotnet restore "MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api"
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "MicroServicesRabitMq/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish MicroServicesRabitMq/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api -c Release -o MicroServicesRabitMq/MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api/out

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MicroServicesRabitMq.Banking.Api.dll"]
```